# What is Server.HtmlEncode()?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between using and not using `Server.HtmlDecode()`?

For example:

```
txtLocation.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(awardShowYear.ShowLocation);
txtLocation.Text = awardShowYear.ShowLocation;
```

What is the difference between those two lines of code?

Comment: Is ShowLocation holding HTML? Or a raw string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one:

```
txtLocation.Text = Server.HtmlDecode(awardShowYear.ShowLocation);
```

Will remove any HTML-Encoding from the string and assign the decoded result to the txtLocation.Text.

The second one:

```
txtLocation.Text = awardShowYear.ShowLocation;
```

Will simply assign the string to txtLocation.Text, preserving any HTML encoding that is present.

See [HttpServerUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx)